# ImageJ - Image to Stack in Batch

Tags: imagej

I have .tiff files which contain 25 sections of a stack each.  Is there a way to use the "Image to Stack" command in batch? Each data set contains 60 tiffs for all three channels of color.

Thanks
Christine

Answer (score 3):

The general way to discover how to do these things is to use the macro recorder, which you can find under `Plugins > Macros > Record ...`.  If you then go to `File > Import > Image Sequence...` and select the first file of the sequence as normal, you should see something like the following appear in the recorder:

```
run("Image Sequence...", "open=[/home/mark/a/1.tif] number=60 starting=1 increment=1 scale=100 file=[] or=[] sort");
```

To allow this to work for arbitrary numbers of slices (my example happened to have 60) just leave out the `number=60` bit.  So, for example, to convert this directory of files to a single file from the command-line you can do:

```
imagej -eval 'run("Image Sequence...", "open=[/home/mark/a/1.tif] starting=1 increment=1 scale=100 file=[] or=[] sort"); saveAs("Tiff", "/home/mark/stack.tif");' -batch
```